# Converting a lambda function to an if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, lambda

I'm trying to convert this Python lambda function to an `if-else` statement so that I can add other arguments onto it. Could someone explain how this Lambda would look like if converted to an `if-esle` statement?

```
df['type'] = df[FEATURE_NAME].map(lambda column_name: 'property' if is_categorical(column_name) else 'metric')
```

Comment: it current is an if-else statement

Comment: @PaulH No, it's a conditional expression.

Comment: potato pah-tah-toe

Comment: @PaulH no it isn't, it's a conditional expression. And that is an important distinction, since you cannot put complex statements in lambda functions, they accept only expressions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga see my response to the other person who said nearly the exact same thing

Comment: @PaulH yes, I did, and I was pointing out that you are trivializing a real and important distinction.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in this context, it indeed seems quite trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the answer you're looking for?

```py
def foo(column_name): 
    if is_categorical(column_name):
        return 'property'
    else:
        return 'metric'     

df['type'] = df[FEATURE_NAME].map(foo)
```